# snowflake query to compare a row with all the previous row

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a dataset like below.

| ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 2022-03-01 |
| 100 | 2022-02-10 |
| 100 | 2021-12-15 |
| 100 | 2021-11-30 |
| 200 | 2021-08-05 |
| 200 | 2021-07-10 |

For a particular ID, I need to compare the previous rows to check if they exist in the previous months. So my output table should like below:

| ID | Date | 1MonthAgo | 2MonthAgo | 3MonthAgo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 2022-03-01 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 100 | 2022-02-10 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 100 | 2021-12-15 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 100 | 2021-11-30 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 200 | 2021-08-05 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 200 | 2021-07-10 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I can use the LAG function but I think that one only works for one row before. For a particular ID, I need to look back 3 months if the ID exist or not. Don't need to do any days calculation just month is fine.

Is there any way I can achieve this using sql?
Appreciate any help on this.
Thanks.

Comment: **LAG** allows you to set the starting offset. By default is 1 row, but you can set it to 2, 3, etc. I am not sure if it's a good idea to use this to look for 3 months period. Maybe a stored procedure with the ID as argument is a better idea.

Comment: you example output is wrong because 2021-12-15 is within 2022-03-01 3 month windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is based only on month calculations -

Actual table -

```
select * from PREV_MONTH;
+-----+------------+
|  ID | DT_DATE    |
|-----+------------|
| 100 | 2022-03-01 |
| 100 | 2022-02-10 |
| 100 | 2021-12-15 |
| 100 | 2021-11-30 |
| 200 | 2021-08-05 |
| 200 | 2021-07-10 |
+-----+------------+
```

Query to draw needed result -

```
select id,dt_date,
CASE
when extract(month from add_months(dt_date,-1)) 
IN 
(select extract (month from dt_date) FROM 
prev_month pm1 where pm1.id=prev_month.id)
    then 1
    else 0 end as month_1,
    CASE
    when extract(month from add_months(dt_date,-2)) 
IN 
(select extract (month from dt_date) FROM 
prev_month pm1 where pm1.id=prev_month.id)
    then 1
    else 0 end as month_2,
    CASE
    when extract(month from add_months(dt_date,-3)) 
IN 
(select extract (month from dt_date) FROM 
prev_month pm1 where pm1.id=prev_month.id)
    then 1
    else 0 end as month_3
    from prev_month;
+-----+------------+---------+---------+---------+
|  ID | DT_DATE    | MONTH_1 | MONTH_2 | MONTH_3 |
|-----+------------+---------+---------+---------|
| 100 | 2022-03-01 |       1 |       0 |       1 |
| 100 | 2022-02-10 |       0 |       1 |       1 |
| 100 | 2021-12-15 |       1 |       0 |       0 |
| 100 | 2021-11-30 |       0 |       0 |       0 |
| 200 | 2021-08-05 |       1 |       0 |       0 |
| 200 | 2021-07-10 |       0 |       0 |       0 |
+-----+------------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

So with this CTE for data:

```
with data(ID, DT_DATE) as (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
        (100, '2022-03-01'),
        (100, '2022-02-10'),
        (100, '2021-12-15'),
        (100, '2021-11-30'),
        (200, '2021-08-05'),
        (200, '2021-07-10')
)
```

### Prior month window from each date:

This super NOT high performant code works, if you want to know "there were 1+ values, in the 1,2,3 month window from this date" for each row.

```
SELECT 
    a.id
    ,a.dt_date
    ,count_if(b.dt_date >= dateadd('month',-1, a.dt_date) and b.dt_date < dateadd('month', 0, a.dt_date))::int as "1monthago"
    ,count_if(b.dt_date >= dateadd('month',-2, a.dt_date) and b.dt_date < dateadd('month', -1, a.dt_date))::int as "2monthago"
    ,count_if(b.dt_date >= dateadd('month',-3, a.dt_date) and b.dt_date < dateadd('month', -2, a.dt_date))::int as "3monthago"
FROM data AS a
LEFT JOIN data AS b 
    ON a.id = b.id AND b.dt_date < a.dt_date
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1,2 desc;
```

| ID | DT_DATE | 1monthago | 2monthago | 3monthago |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 2022-03-01 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 100 | 2022-02-10 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 100 | 2021-12-15 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 100 | 2021-11-30 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 200 | 2021-08-05 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 200 | 2021-07-10 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

### Prior named month:

```
SELECT 
    a.id
    ,a.dt_date
    ,count_if(date_trunc('month', dateadd('month',-1, a.dt_date)) = date_trunc('month', b.dt_date))::int as "1monthago"
    ,count_if(date_trunc('month', dateadd('month',-2, a.dt_date)) = date_trunc('month', b.dt_date))::int as "2monthago"
    ,count_if(date_trunc('month', dateadd('month',-3, a.dt_date)) = date_trunc('month', b.dt_date))::int as "3monthago"
FROM data AS a
LEFT JOIN data AS b 
    ON a.id = b.id AND b.dt_date < a.dt_date
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1,2 desc;
```

| ID | DT_DATE | 1monthago | 2monthago | 3monthago |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 2022-03-01 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 100 | 2022-02-10 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 100 | 2021-12-15 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 100 | 2021-11-30 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 200 | 2021-08-05 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 200 | 2021-07-10 | 0 | 0 | 0 |